# For Apple Watch + Cellular models, how do they manage active calls when going out of Bluetooth range from their paired iPhone?

Tags: apple-watch

The following example assumes that we have an Apple Watch Cellular model that is connected over Bluetooth to its paired  iPhone:

1. An incoming call is received by both the Apple Watch and its paired iPhone. The wearer of the Watch decides to answer the call directly on the Watch
2. During the call, the wearer of the Watch moves out of Bluetooth range of its paired iPhone - in this example, there are no nearby Wi-Fi networks that the Watch can connect to

In the above situation, how would the Watch manage the call? Does it have the capability of switching from Bluetooth to cellular for calls that are currently in progress, or would the call simply be dropped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's doesn't have the capability of switching from Bluetooth to cellular for calls that are currently in progress, so the call would simply be dropped.

When you answer a call on your iPhone and hand it off to the Apple Watch, the watch doesn't actually communicate with the cell network to transition the call from the iPhone's cellular connection to the watch's cellular connection. That's not how it works. This is because that is actually a pretty complicated process that takes a lot of time (i.e. you would be left without a call for several seconds).

What actually happens is that the call is simply "forwarded" on from the iPhone to the watch using Bluetooth/WiFi ([Handing off phone calls to Apple Watch, last paragraph](https://www.ilounge.com/index.php/tips/comments/handing-off-phone-calls-to-apple-watch)). The call is technically still terminated on the iPhone, and thus the cellular modem on the watch is not in play. You must remain within range of your iPhone to keep the call - if you go outside range, the call is dropped. You can then dial up again from the Watch to create a new call ofcourse.

When you answer a call on your Apple Watch and the call is terminated on the watch via your eSIM, you can indeed go out of range of the iPhone without any problems. However this is only the case if the iPhone was never involved in the call at all - and doesn't apply to the situation you describe, where the call was going to the Watch over Bluetooth initially.

Comment: *What actually happens is that the call is simply "forwarded" on from the iPhone to the watch using Bluetooth/WiFi.* No!  A device connected via Bluetooh pairs with a particular profile - in this case a *headset* profile.  WiFi connectivity works like handoff does with a Mac computer.  Since an iWatch doesn't have a phone number and Bluetooth is not a telco protocol, nothing can be forwarded even in the most broadest description.  If you think my answer is incorrect, show evidence - this is a guess based on a complete lack of understanding of how any of the underlying technology works.

Comment: I'm sorry if you're offended that I think your answer to the question is not correct, but I think you're perhaps going a bit over the top here. The word forwarded was put in quotes to emphasize that it is not a technical term for what happens, but merely an explanation for a layman. That doesn't mean that I have a complete lack of understanding of underlying technology. Actually it seems that you're actually incorrect in assuming it uses the headset profile - where it is actually the hands-free profile that is used. But that's just nitpicking that doesn't actually help answer the original ...

Comment: question. I just fail to see how your "more than likely" is not a guess, where my information based on experience with the Apple Watch is. I'll find a link or two to back up what I wrote...

Comment: I don't think you read the link in your answer.  Headset vs. speakerphone profile is a distinction without a difference in the context of your answer because regardless of the actual profile used, the way you describe how this works is completely incorrect.

Comment: [I don't see how that comment is helpful?] You've since changed your comment, so I have put mine in quotes here.

Comment: What you posted and what the article says are opposite.

Comment: How so? I think it says the exact same: "Unfortunately, you’ll still need to stay in range of your iPhone even if you have a cellular-capable Apple Watch Series 3, since this method doesn’t do an actual transfer of the call; it’s more like using the Apple Watch as a remote speakerphone."

Comment: Note that I have also actually tried this in practice. If I transfer a call to my Watch, and go out of range of the phone - the call drops. And yes, I've got an active eSIM on the watch. At least for me, there do not seem to be any "magic" happening that activates the radios on the watch to get my cell provider to handover the call to the watch.

Comment: Your back with that insignificant point.  I'm saying that what the article describes as to how it all works and what you describe in your answer are opposite.  Case in point - you use the term "forward" to describe what happens, yet the article uses the term "handoff" literally in the title.  And in real life, calls often drop on *any* phone going between cell towers.  It happens all the time - so saying that "it drops"   doesn't support your argument.

Comment: You seem to have stopped arguing about the actual question, and gone off on a tangent now. If I'm speaking to someone on a call on my Watch and the actual connection is going through my phone (somehow) - and I move out of range - what happens? - That is the question. Your answer is that "it just works" and my answer is that the "call is dropped". You're trying to argue the semantics of "forward" which doesn't seem to in any way help the answering of the question. But I guess like you asked me for proof - you can then provide proof that the call is not dropped?

Comment: I don't think you understood my answer either.

Comment: You do not seem to have an interest in the actual question, but merely in insulting me. If that's your idea of fun, I'm not participating. I'll let @elliot94 try it out and get back with the results... (and yes, I have noted that you changed your answer to basically say the opposite of what it did originally...)

Comment: read the  first two lines of your answer and re-evaluate that last comment.

Comment: So you're saying you found that line insulting? - I was just quoting the answer so it would be clear what I was referring to, in case there would be multiple answers later on.

Comment: Do you always assume intent or is it the way *you* would respond if the roles were reversed?  You're quoting an answer which you don't actually rebut, but make a wild guess then get your nose out of joint when your behavior is called out.  Write your answer and leave others out of it.  In every answer I have ever written, I have ***never*** referenced another user saying they are wrong; it is bad form to do that.  I

Comment: I had no idea it was bad form to reference other answers to the same question - I have done that loads of times. I'm sorry if I offended you, but I don't see why it's just to call my answer a "wild guess" when mine's based on actual experience with the Watch.

Comment: For the record, you don't offend nor insult me, so please stop.  As for a "wild guess"  - this statement lends credence to it:  "This is because that is actually a pretty complicated process that takes a lot of time (i.e. you would be left without a call for several seconds)."  If that were the case, every time you drove down the street all of your calls would drop as the calls were handed over from cell to cell.   While they do drop (it's not perfect) it's not very common.  You're approaching this as if the iWatch and iPhone are distinct when they're more like extension on the same phone line

Comment: What you're talking about there is handoff between cell towers. This question was about moving the call from one UE to another. It's a different thing.

Comment: That was used as an example to illustrate the technology and process.  Since the SIM in the watch and phone both go to the same account, it's super easy to "pick up" the extension on the line and join the call.

Comment: I don't think you have taken into account for example that cell radio on the Watch is not turned on while you're taking the call via the iPhone. It takes time to power on, attach to the network, request a connection over RRC, authenticate to the network, create an IMS session and register. Even considering that, I haven't seen that it is a requirement for providers to be able to support such a "pick up the extension" feature.

Comment: My sentence in the answer as posted from the beginning:  " More than likely, the watch is already connected to the call because it’s directly linked to the account."  It's not a feature that needs to be implemented as carriers can already tap into and access existing calls - how do you think call recording of cell phones happens when complying with a warrant?

Comment: My experience with the actual device is that it is not connected to the call, nor is it attached to LTE at the same time. Attaching to LTE on the watch usually takes a while. Have you got actual experience with it or some docs you can refer to or something?

Comment: I have actual, real life experience in telco. The chip isn't starting from "cold" and would be in "standby"  similar to what happens in airplane mode.  Go in and out of airplane mode, it connects within a second.

Comment: I've worked at a telco for more than 5 years (as a developer working with SIP and other stuff), so I have that too. I've just tested it on an actual device. It took a bit more than 7 seconds - and I have a pretty good signal here.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely it would be handled the same way a cellular phone transitions between cell towers while moving - [hand off or handover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handover). Basically while connected to one tower, it connects to another to make the transition seamless.

Now, remember, the iWatch has an eSIM attached to it which itself is linked to the iPhone’s account.  That watch simply has to connect to the cell network as the radio signal starts to degrade and the call is handed off.  More than likely, the watch is *already* connected to the call because it’s directly linked to the account.

**Bluetooth Profiles**

Most folks generally take "connected via Bluetooth" for granted that it's just "connected" and your iWatch likes your iPhone.  That's not the case.  When connected via Bluetooth, it must do so with a specific [Bluetooth Profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles), usually a headset profile because it's providing mic, earphones, hold, dial, volume up/down features.  It's acting exactly how a BT headset would work and would "react" the same way if it went out of range of the iPhone - it would disconnect.

**WiFi**

You can think of the WiFi connectivity between your iPhone and you iWatch as the same as the [Apple Handoff](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/hand-off-between-devices-mchl732d3c0a/mac) works with your iOS devices and your Mac.  For example, when Handoff is enabled and my iPhone and iMac are on the same network, I can make and receive calls on my iMac.  What's happening is I'm making a call on my iPhone *through* my iMac.